# Omitting "to be": "I want left alone." versus "I want to be left alone."

Tags: ellipsis, syntax, dialect

I have been reading an internet serial for about a year, that is written by someone I believe to be a native or near-native English speaker (like myself), but I have noticed a recurring pattern of sentences that don't scan fully and was wondering if this is perhaps a dialect, stylistic choice, or misunderstanding.

For example, the author will write "(the cat) Floofy would want fed and petted", which I take to mean "(the cat) Floofy would want *to be* fed and petted". The author also writes, on multiple occasions as it is important to the plot, "I just want left alone", again omitting to be, which makes me think that this is either a constant misunderstanding or dialect. Personally, I think the second sentence scans better and feels almost natural, which I think is because I read it as "I just want *leaving* alone", but this has bugged me for a while. Is it correct English? A dialect I've never heard?

I am confused because this author has a perfect understanding of English everywhere else. Searching online has not yielded any help, any ideas?

Comment: I guess it's a dialect, but it's one I've never heard of (SE USA).

Comment: Possibly expressions like 'want fed', 'want left alone' are part of the local dialect of the author (and used unconsciously), or the author has deliberately made the character use them. The usage is found in informal writing and speech in the UK and USA, but is decidedly not standard English. Expressions like 'Your hair wants cutting' are found in Yorkshire (UK) dialects. I found this in _Underworld_ (2007) by Don DeLillo, an American novelist -  “That's what he wants. Left alone to grow up without advice from you. Only he won't say it himself.”

Comment: You may find this post on EL&U interesting: [Central Pennsylvanian English speakers: what are the limitations on the “needs washed” construction?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/5407/80039) One answer says *if standard English would use wants|needs|requires + gerund, the Central PA dialect is likely to use wants|needs|requires + past tense*

Comment: Note that "wants cutting" is different from "wants cut", which would be the equivalent of what @flumperious described.  I'm from the north of England and the "wants cutting" construction is familiar (though it probably wouldn't be considered correct in a formal document).  "Wants cut", on the other hand, is a construction I've only ever heard from America, where it seems to be widespread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like the "needs washed" construction, as reported by [Yale](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/needs-washed):

> The most common verb associated with this construction is *need*. However, Murray and Simon (2002) show that *want* and *like* are sometimes possible as well, as in the following examples:
>
> > 3. Cindy, this one [baby] just woke up and probably wants fed.
> > 4. [The dog] sure does like petted.

There are several dialects that use this:

> Murray and Simon (2002) describe the rough boundaries as Western Pennsylvania, Eastern Ohio, Northern West Virginia, and Central Indiana. Pockets of speakers may exist in places as far-spread as Kentucky and Illinois. This construction is also attested in Scots English, which might be its historical source.

Comment: that sounds about right, and looking at it now i could have sworn i'd read something about "needs washed" or heard it somewhere